# Sample UDEV file for Stellaris Launchpad

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev, launchpad

I'm trying to get my **Stellaris Launchpad** to work with the **Energia IDE**.
I'm told to upload programs and to run the serial port I've got to **create a udev entry**.

I'm relatively new to linux (although not Ubuntu) so could anyone please provide me with a sample udev file.

My Stellaris board's on port /dev/ttyACM0, VID=1cbe and PID=00fd.

As of now I'm using this ->

```
# 
# This file allows non-root access to TI stellaris launchpad
# See udev(7) for syntax.
#
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTRS{idVendor}=="1cbe",ATTRS{idProduct}=="00fd",MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM0",ATTRS{idVendor}=="1cbe",ATTRS{idProduct}=="00fd",MODE="0666"
#
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: New to Linux but not new to Ubuntu, huh??

Comment: I have used Ubuntu as a basic desktop with basic terminal usage and experience. But I don't have much experience into the core of Linux like scripting, device files, etc. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

For those with the same or a similar problem. Here's the simple solution.

**Step 1:** Add your username to the "dialout" group. In terminal type,

```
sudo adduser <username> dialout
```

**Step 2:** Create a udev (eg: 61-stellpad.rules) file in the directory: /etc/udev/rules.d/
with the contents as,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1cbe", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00fd", MODE="0666"
```

**Step 3:** Save, unplug and replug the Stellaris board. All done.

**[Note]:** The solution was provided by a fellow Stellaris Launchpad user - Bernard.

Works perfectly now.

Cheers.

Comment: 0666 means any program can access the file, so all security, including group ownership, goes out the window. Never give _o_ther (the last digit) write permission (6 or 7).